# Is there an easy way to clean up a bootstrap wrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Looked around without much luck. 
In short, I purchased a wrap that has almost 30k lines of css. I want to get just the needed css for 1 page which will probably be 1000 lines of css.

Found a couple plugins to speed it up, but it's still a very manual process grabbing each class 1 at a time.

Is there anything out there to make it easier?

The bad part, they copied all the bootstrap code into a new file and made the changes there. 90% is the original bootstrap css.

Found the Dust-me firefox plugin, but it just lists the used css classes, so it's still a manual process going to their css and copying each class 1 at a time and having to make sure it's not the same as the bootstrap classes.

With all the wraps out there, I would figure this is somewhat common, since most are pretty messy. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Try an online tool like [unused-css](http://www.unused-css.com) to isolate just those styles used on the page.

To isolate non-bootstrap code, determine the bootstrap version they used; you can run a diff on your wrap vs. the bootstrap distributed file. [Try an online app like diffchecker](https://www.diffchecker.com/) and hopefully most of it was just untouched bootstrap css like you said.

Comment: Agreed. That's an option. Still mostly manual. Would rather not spend 8+ hours doing 1 class at a time. It may even take me less time to write something automating it. Just that simple, I am just surprised I haven't found a better way of automating it out there.

Comment: I think I missed your intention. Would something like this work? https://unused-css.com

Comment: Thanks Richard. I will try that out tonight. Looks like what I'm looking for.

Comment: Appreciate it. Not perfect, but cuts off hours of work and doubt I will find better. For others looking at using it. It will break it down to the class, but it won't clean up the class itself. So if there are 10 attributes in a css class and 1 is different, you still get all 10.